# Creating an auto-DJ app

Tags: waveform, audio-player

I'm trying to create an 'auto dj' application that would let smartphone users select a playlist of songs, and it would create a seamless mix for playback. There are a couple factors involved in this: read a playlist of audio files, calculate their waveforms/spectrums, determine the BPMs, and organize the compatible songs in a new playlist in the order that they will be played (based on compatible tempos & keys).

The app would have to be able to scan the waveform of a song and recognize the beginning of the 'main' part of the song (skipping slow intros/outros). I also imagine having some effects: filtering, so it can filter the bass out of the new track being mixed in, and switch the basses at an appropriate time. Perhaps reverb that the user could control as well.

I am just seeing how feasible of a project this is for 3-4 busy college students in the span of ~4 months. Not sure if it would be an Android or iOS app, or perhaps even a Windows app. Not sure what language we would use (likely Python or Java); whichever has the most useful audio analyzing libraries. Obviously it would work better for certain genres of music (house, trance), but I'd still really like to try to create this.

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 1):

As much as I would like to hear a more experienced person's opinion on this, I would say based on your situation that it would be a very big undertaking. Since it sounds like you don't have experience using audio analyzing libraries/ programs you might want to start experimenting with those and most of them are likely going to be in C/ C++, not java/ Python. Here are some I know of but I would recommend do your own research.

http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/
http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

It doesn't sound that feasible in your situation but that just depends on your programming/project experience and motivation to create it.

Good luck